# I'm using Pandas to fix an email list on a column using .replace() but isn't working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to fix truncated email addresses using Pandas replace() method, I followed several online tutorials, but the results I am getting aren't what I want.
this is my first try

```
filtered_users_emails = pd.read_csv('list_users.csv')
filtered_users_emails_replaced = filtered_users_emails.replace({
                                                              '.c': '.com',
                                                              '.co': '.com'
                                                             })
```

and the second one using Regex gave me unexpected results

```
filtered_users_emails = pd.read_csv('list_users.csv')
filtered_users_emails_replaced = filtered_users_emails.replace({
                                                              '.c': '.com',
                                                              '.co': '.com'
                                                             },
                                                             regex=True)
```

From the above you can see I am trying to replace truncated emails ending in .c and .co, to end as expected in .com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
filtered_users_emails['email'] = filtered_users_emails['email'].str.replace('.com*','.c', regex=True) filtered_users_emails['email'] = filtered_users_emails['email'].str.replace('.c','.com', regex=True)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, to be honest I wasn't sure, because I saw two lines of code into one ... and I thought they were independent, but I tried it as is, just spliting code into two lines and it worked, I'm curious about why you had to apply the str.replace attribute twice! ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
filtered_users_emails ['email'] = filtered_users_emails ['email'].str.replace('.co','.com')
```

Comment: It didn't work these are some results >>>

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it didn't work these are some results >>>
 email
89 aaziz@justbooking.comm
90 ab@affordabl.comndos.comm
91 abaca@lyo.comuntry.comm
92 abachamary@caramail.comm

It replaced all instances of .co into .com not just the one in the end, just like when I applied regex=True ...

I read there are ways to target what occurrence of the substring with a number, but in my case, I don't know if there are multiple matches within the string, so it's impossible to know the position considering there are over 78,000 emails on that column.